# __IOS_UNAVAIBLE makes it __TVOS_UNAVAILABLE too?

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos

Am I going crazy, or is it just me? I've marked different properties, classes and functions as `__IOS_UNAVAILABLE`. However, when I do this it also makes the property, class or function unavailable on tvOS as well. Is this a bug or something?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is similar to the `TARGET_OS_….` macros, which when building for tvOS returns true for `TARGET_OS_MAC`, `TARGET_OS_IOS`, and `TARGET_OS_TV`. The idea being tvOS is a version of iOS which is a version of macOS historically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `__IOS_UNAVAILABLE` and `__TVOS_UNAVAILABLE` in your own code.  Those are specifically for use by the OS SDKs for annotating what version of the OS introduced certain functionality.

It is expected that `__IOS_UNAVAILABLE` will cause it it be unavailable on tvOS and watchOS unless explicitly marked as available on those platforms (as they inherit from iOS).